# Link to static HTML page from within Svelte component

Tags: javascript, svelte, window.location

How can I move from a Svelte component to an HTML file using window.location.href?

I tried various combinations, but the HTML can't be found. Do I have to set up routing?

Folder Structure:

```
project
├── example.html
├── svelteProject
    ├── src
        ├── App.svelte
```

Comment: You need routing, juste use svelte-kit.

Comment: Missing context, e.g. how you build and serve the application.

Answer (score 0):

The most ideal thing would be to use Sveltekit. You could also try to create a full page iframe, not sure how you'd reference your HTML file though.